# Strange behaviour of pie diagrams in QGIS -- Pies "disappear" while zooming out

Tags: qgis, diagram

I'm trying to create a pie diagram. But when I zoom in and out the pies disappear! See Attachment for the data? My mistake?  Bug? Anyone?

Video: https://politikvonunten.org/extern/simplescreenrecorder4aaa-2024-01-02_19.23.06.mp4 Shape-Files: https://politikvonunten.org/extern/pie-diagram-points.zip

Sorry, now with the correct video file...

Also see the whole project, as it might be a projection issue:
https://politikvonunten.org/extern/project.zip

Comment: Please provide settings, as well as images of scale and map.

Comment: Not able to download your file. Can you try another service, like WeTransfer, DropBox, etc...?

Comment: Still can't download your data. Link asks me to "create account" and sign in. Please use WeTransfer, MEGA, or DropBox. And please add screen shots to your question.

Comment: Sorry, file dowonload indeed does not work - we don't have the same view as you have on your screenrecord, so the video does not help. You seem to have an account. Without being logged in, it is not possible to download the data. Please provide the data in another way, as mentioned before.

Comment: Sorry, here it should work: https://politikvonunten.org/extern/pie-diagram-points.zip

Comment: ok now all files are on my own server and should work

Comment: Your data is missing projection information. Which CRS are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to use EPSG:32633. So UTM33N WGS84. But I tried to assign this projection to the layers but it doesn't seem to be working. Here my project including the layers an the qgz file: https://politikvonunten.org/extern/project.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is the solution:

1. Repjoject all layers to EPSG:32633: - Vector --> Data management tools --> Layer reprojection
2. Then save all reprojected layers as new shape files
3. Create new project, import all reprojected shapes

Now it works.